# Why doesn't MPI_SEND work within my for loop? It works fine if explicitly stated

Tags: c, process, segmentation-fault, mpi

I'm trying to send a number to p-1 processes. Process 0 sends this value to all other processes. I use an MPI_SEND Command to do this. When I explicitly write out MPI_SEND commands for 3 processes, it works fine. But when I want to put it in a loop, it gives me the output as well as a segmentation fault code. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include "a1.h"

//AUTHORS
//LAKSHAN SIVANANTHAN - 1150161
//RAZMIG PAPISSIAN - 1152517

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  RGB *image;
  int width, height, max;
  int windowLength = atoi(argv[3]);
  int my_rank, p, local_height, source, i;

  int dest;

  MPI_Status status;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

  int *processorRows;
  processorRows = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(p+1));

  if (my_rank == 0) {

    printf("Process %d is reading...\n", my_rank);
    image = readPPM(argv[1], &width, &height, &max); 

    //calculate rows to each process

    for (i=0; i<p; i++) {

      processorRows[i] = height/p;

    }

    for (i=0; i< height%p; i++){

      processorRows[i]++;
    }

    for (dest=1; dest<p; dest++) {

      MPI_Send(processorRows + dest, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      //MPI_Send(processorRows + 2, 1, MPI_INT, 2, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      //MPI_Send(processorRows + 3, 1, MPI_INT, 3, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

  }
  else {

    MPI_Recv(processorRows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    printf("I am Process %d and will run %d rows...\n", my_rank, *processorRows);

  } 

  //processImage(width, height, image, windowLength);
  //writePPM(argv[2], width, height, max, image);

  free(image);
  free(processorRows);

  MPI_Finalize();
  return(0);

}
```

If I were to remove the for loop, replace "dest" with 1, and uncomment the other 2 MPI_SEND lines, it works completely fine when running mpirun -np 4 ./program

Not sure what's going on here...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish. But, from the statement

> Process 0 sends this value to all other processes.

and from the part of the code, I would expect you to do a scatter from Process-0 to all other PEs rather than this send-receive loop tricks.

Remove all the send-receive pairs and remove the loops, just use a single scatter operation. Here is the link for MPI_Scatter operation https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Scatter.3.php. If you are unsure about the scatter operation, have a look at this neat explanation http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-scatter-gather-and-allgather/

It looks like, the size of *processorRows* array is the size of the total number of Process used. And, you are trying to send each element of this *processorRows* array to all other ranks. Hence, your code should look something like this one below:

```
int *processorRows;
processorRows = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(p+1));

if (my_rank == 0) {
    printf("Process %d is reading...\n", my_rank);
    image = readPPM(argv[1], &width, &height, &max); 

    for (i=0; i<p; i++) {
        processorRows[i] = height/p;
    }

    for (i=0; i< height%p; i++){
        processorRows[i]++;
    }
}   
MPI_Scatter(processorRows, 1, MPI_INT, processorRows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the

```
#include "a.h"
```

and

```
image = readPPM(argv[1], &width, &height, &max);
```

since I do not have these classes, set the height manually to 10 and the code worked. Maybe the problem is with `height` variable?

Comment: Though this suggests us the possible source of this error; there are other things in terms of using MPI, are fundamentally unnecessary in the first place;

Comment: 1. Missing to use the MPI_Collectives(scatter in this case) and trying to implement a hand-coded algorithm with send-receive  2. I don't even know why he should maintain an array of *processorRows*, essentially he just need to send the height from *rank==0* to every PEs and each PE can calculate its own *local_height*. These two suggestions can completely remove the cause for this error.

Comment: And, also we should remember that the author says *When I explicitly write out MPI_SEND commands for 3 processes, it works fine.*, so if this statement is actually correct, then we getting *height* from *image* should also be correct !!!